# Adding assets to Xcode problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, svn

I've an Xcode project which has been using svn, but we had to stop using it. Since then when ever I try and Add files to the project I get the error window below. The files actually get added to the file system (using Finder), but not to the project,so not displayed in the file system in XCode and therefore can't be accessed.

[image: Error window]

Comment: are they @2x files? i ran into a similar problem...

Comment: See this if they are. http://superuser.com/questions/183020/how-to-escape-the-at-sign-in-bash

Comment: No they seem to be any files...

Comment: Ah found the answer somewhere...just make sure you delete all the hidden .svn files / folders

Comment: Put that as the answer and give yourself the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Just make sure you delete all the hidden .svn files / folders