# in Xcode 4 how to associate a project to the local Git repository I set up?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4, organizer

in Xcode 4 how to associate a project to the local Git repository I set up?

That is:

- I've set up a Git repository after the Xcode 4 project was already created, based on instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW8):
- I've gone to Organizer and "added" this as a local Git repository
- When I go to my project in Xcode 4 the source code functions still don't appear to work - I'm guessing it because there must be some way of tying the Xcode Project wiht the local repository I created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From "[How to Create Git Repos for Existing Xcode Projects](http://coffeetimerapp.com/index.php/2011/03/how-to-create-git-repos-for-existing-xcode-projects/)":

> UPDATE: Apparently just initializing an empty repository in the project directory is enough; Xcode autodetects it for you.
>   It be nice if something to that effect was in the documentation. Thanks to Jason for that ([details here](http://nearthespeedoflight.com/article/creating_a_git_repository_for_an_existing_xcode_project)). Open the project directory in a terminal and type the following:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

So in your case, it should detect it.

The [OP Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173520/greg) comments:

> I found out that all I had to do was **change a file, and then the Xcode 4 pop up menu for the file did show a source control set of options (previously greyed out)**.
>   So the initial part of the answer is correct re the manual git commands for creating the git repository.

---

Otherwise you can try:

- make a new XCode4 project with a(n empty) git repo in it
- move your .git directory and override the Xcode 4 project .git
- move the sources in that new Xcode 4 project directory
- see if XCode4 then detect your sources *and* the Git integration

Not your case probably, but [one of the comments mentions](http://coffeetimerapp.com/index.php/2011/03/how-to-create-git-repos-for-existing-xcode-projects/#comment-611):

> If you're switching from an SVN repository (which I was), the trick is to go into your project folder and delete or rename the `.svn` directory.
>   For me it seemed that Xcode would find the `.svn` folder first (or preferred it, even though the backing repository was decommissioned), but once it was gone Xcode would happily start using the git repository.

That was actually the [issue for another Xcode 4 Git user here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264848/adding-assets-to-xcode-problem/7265200#7265200).

Comment: I think I'm going to have to try creating the new project as the method - can't quite get it to work otherwise

Comment: Doh - I found out that all I had to do was change a file, and then the XCode4 pop up menu for the file did show a source control set of options (previously greyed out).  So the initial part of the answer is correct re the manual git commands for creating the git repository.

Comment: @Greg: excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer, for more visibility.

Comment: where is the git repository stored in the file system?